# Can you declare a property with a custom getter, default setter and no initializer in Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I have a property with a getter, default setter and no initializer like this:

```
    var test: String
        get() = "test value"
        private set
```

If I try this code in Android studio I get a compile error stating that `Property must be initialized`. If I instead try it at [try.kotlinlang.org](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Examples/Hello,%20world!/Simplest%20version/Simplest%20version.kt) the code runs fine and `test value` is returned whenever I access the property.

I'm trying to read the Kotlin [documentation for properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html), but I can't really tell if this is supposed to work or not.

Is this valid Kotlin code or not?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? With an implementation like this one, the values assigned to the property will simply be ignored.

Comment: Why not `val test = "test value"` then?

Comment: In my original case the getter would call a function that returned different values depending on when it was called. For a while I had the idea that `val` means a property always return the same value. So I thought having it return different values each time it's called would be confusing. So I tried to make a read only `var` instead. But I then realized that `val` just means read only and not constant. So I'm not using this code, I'm just trying to understand the language better.

Comment: I have also tested the code with the exact same kotlin version and have obtained the same results. I would recommend submitting an [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT) for this because the difference is most likely not intentional.

Comment: @Anton, based on the answer from tynn and reading the documentation again. I believe that it is correct to give a compilation error in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [try.kotlinlang.org](https://try.kotlinlang.org) also accepts an uninitialized `val` returning `null` though it is non-nullable:

```
var test: String
    private set
```

Your intent is possible if you make the `var` not field-backed at all:

```
var test: String
    get() = "test value"
    private set(value) = Unit
```

For the [Backing Fields](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields) the documentation states:

> A backing field will be generated for a property if it uses the default implementation of at least one of the accessors, or if a custom accessor references it through the `field` identifier.

Comment: Aha! Since I use the default implementation of the set accessor it will generate a backing field and since it has a backing field it must be initialized.

Comment: Is the behaviour on try.kotlinlang.org correct? Shouldn't it give the same compilation error as in the IDE?

Comment: @user2340612 I'm not sure if it's a compile or lint error in AS, but since in TRY the property is `null` when it's not initialized, it seems to be wrong there.